# Facebook Page Tab: 191 API error OR infinite loop

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth, facebook-canvas

My Facebook Page Tab isn't working since last thursday (28-11-2012).
In developers.facebook.com I set "App on Facebook" and "Page Tab".

The source:

```
    $app_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    //$canvas_page = "https://facebook.com/my_facebook_page?sk=app_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $canvas_page = "http://my-promotion.domain.com";
    $application_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $app_id,
        'secret' => $application_secret,
        'cookie' => true, 
    ));

    $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope=user_likes,publish_actions";
    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
```

**1.** If I set the $canvas_page like https://facebook.com/my_facebook_page?sk=app_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX I will get an error when I click on the Page Tab (on the Facebook Page):

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: De opgegeven URL wordt niet toegestaan door de configuratie van de applicatie.
```

**2.** If I set the $canvas_page to the Canvas URL (declared in my app on developers.facebook.com) - http://my-promotion.domain.com/ - I will get the Auth Dialog. But after giving permission I get an infinite loop like:

=">http://my-promotion.domain.com/?code=AQC_wreWvGJuZQC07I5Kyps79JIeuRv718wWoWYb94A_RlxagWWRQOBQp0xQUAjG6rWAHDrVWEo851udcTC9jWHor980h2ipQ67LLKgYEfvKN71bjMO3y9SzHjiGtpIiCZHd3L6gHgM3Vmzpw3NvpMxXCXIUQtYOsEeOJAOws5rY3IaTCMo5Al-cO5zFPd2K0sHnbXbDo2JAyYTNm5skW-0i#*=*
(the value of ?code changes continuous)

Before 28-11-2012 my Page Tabs were always working, if I set the $canvas_page like option 1.